# Set $S$ of integers $\ge0$ such that $\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$ partitions into $A, B$ with $\sum_\limits{a\in A}a^k=\sum_\limits{b\in B}b^k$ for all $k\in S$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, recreational-mathematics, set-partition

> Let $s_n$ be the largest size of a set $S$ of integers $\ge0$ st there exist two subsets $A,B\subseteq \{1,2,...,n\}$ that satisfy the conditions
>
> (1) $A\cap B=\emptyset$,
>
> (2) $A\cup B=\{1,2,...,n\}$,
>
> (3) $\sum_\limits{a\in A}a^k=\sum_\limits{b\in B}b^k$ for all $k\in S$.
>
> What is $s_n$?  What is an example for $S,A,B$ in the case $|S|=s_n$?

This question is inspired by a question my teacher asked me.  The original question was to show that $\{1,2,...,2^m\}$ can be partitioned into two sets $A,B$ of equal size st $\sum_\limits{a\in A}a^k=\sum_\limits{b\in B}b^k$ for $k=0,1,...,(m-1).\quad$  I solved that problem (by induction on m) and wonder about what happens if I replace $2^m$ by other integers $n$.

First $s_n=0$ for all $n\equiv 1\pmod{4}$ because the number of odd numbers in $\{1,2,...,n\}$ is odd.  Then $s_n=1$ for all $n\equiv 2\pmod{4}$ using the same reason and only $S=\{0\}$ works.  For $n=2^mt\space$ where $t$ is odd and $m\ge 2$, I know from the question my teacher asked me that $s_n\ge m$ because $S=\{0,1,...,m-1\}$ is an example.  I'm not sure whether $s_n=m$ in these cases.  Please help me solve the case $n=2^mt\space$ where $t$ is odd and $m\ge 2$.

Comment: You might be interested in [this paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2021-90-329/S0025-5718-2021-03612-1/home.html) soon to be published in Mathematics of Computation.  Arxiv version is [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.03491).